# Set a different asset host for a specific asset_path in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Does anyone know if it's possible to somehow set a different asset_host for a asset that is addressed using the asset_path or asset_url helper method?

Something like this:

```
asset_path 'path/to/asset.html', :host => nil #this will same sure the asset is on the same domain
asset_path 'path/to/asset.jpg', :host => 'http://staticserver.com' #static server
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This can be achieved by doing the following:

```
def custom_asset_path(asset)
  config = MyApp::Application.config.action_controller
  asset_host = config.asset_host
  config.asset_host = "http://custom-asset-server.com"
  path = asset_path(asset)
  config.asset_host = asset_host
  path
end
```